# Time of first occurrence of the query from pg_stat_statements. Possible to get?

Tags: postgresql, profiling, database-performance, postgresql-9.6

I'm debugging a DB performance issue. There's a lead that the issue was introduced after a certain deploy, e.g. when DB started to serve some new queries.

I'm looking to correlate deployment time with the performance issues, and would like to identify the queries that are causing this.

Using `pg_stat_statements` has been very handy so far. Unfortunately it does not store the time stamp of the first occurrence of each query.

**Is there any auxiliary tables I could look into to see the time of first occurrence of queries?**

Ideally, if this information would have been available in `pg_stat_statements`, I'd make a query like this:

```
select queryid from where date(first_run) = '2020-04-01';
```

Additionally, it'd be cool to see `last_run` as well, so to filter out some old queries that no longer execute at all, but remain in `pg_stat_statements`. That's more of a nice thing that's a necessity though.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not stored anywhere, and indeed it would not be very useful. If the problem statement is a new one, you can easily identify it in your application code. If it is not a new statement, but something made the query slower, the first time the query was executed won't help you.

Is your source code not under version control?

Comment: the source code is under my control. Problem is, a refactoring consisting of thousand of lines was deployed, and substantial changes to the DB schema were made. It makes it tricky to look at the problem from the application angle, so I took my chances to see if there's anything I am able learn from the DB itself.